# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto - (objetos não estão nulos)

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception

Boa tarde,

Não entendo alguns conceitos e estou com grande dúvida referente a esse problema, fiz algumas pesquisas pra tentar identificar, porém sem sucesso.

Tenho esse código e está retornando erro na hora de chamar o método Log2

```
Parallel.ForEach(grupoServidores, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 80 },
servidor =>
{
    //Console.WriteLine((servidor);
    //Console.WriteLine((servidor);
    string mensagem = servidor;
    //Console.WriteLine((mensagem);

    // Variavel de timeout da thread
    var timeout = 30; // 22 seconds

    //Variavel de latencia da thread

    DateTime dataCheck = DateTime.Now;


    //Thread paralela com timeout
    Thread threadAgent = new Thread(() => AgentCheckThread(mensagem));
    threadAgent.IsBackground = true;
    threadAgent.Name = "Agent";
    threadAgent.Start();

    //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ":Estado da thread assim que inicia: " + threadAgent.ThreadState + " para o servidor: " + mensagem);
    Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ";" + "Servidor=" + mensagem + ";" + "Processo=INICIO");
    while (threadAgent.ThreadState.ToString() != "Stopped" && DateTime.Now.Subtract(dataCheck) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
    {

    }

    //Verifica o resultado da consulta
    TimeSpan dataCheck2 = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dataCheck);
    TimeSpan timeoutCheck = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    try
    {
        if (listaServidores[listaServidores.FindIndex(s => s.Nome_Servidor == mensagem)].Status_Servidor == "OK")
        {

            Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ";" + "Servidor=" + mensagem + ";" + "Processo=FIM;Status=OK");
            threadsFinalizadas++;
            totalThreadsFinalizadas++;
        }
        else if (listaServidores[listaServidores.FindIndex(s => s.Nome_Servidor == mensagem)].Status_Servidor == "ERROR")
        {

            threadsFinalizadas++;
            totalThreadsFinalizadas++;
            Servidor ServidorErro = new Servidor
            {
                Nome_Servidor = mensagem,
                Data_Consulta = listaServidores[listaServidores.FindIndex(s => s.Nome_Servidor == mensagem)].Data_Consulta,
            };
            listaServidoresErro.Add(ServidorErro);


            Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ";" + "Servidor=" + mensagem + ";" + "Processo=FIM;Status=ERROR;Desc=" + listaServidores[listaServidores.FindIndex(s => s.Nome_Servidor == mensagem)].Desc);
            try
            {
                foreach (string erro in listaServidores[listaServidores.FindIndex(s => s.Nome_Servidor == mensagem)].Erros)
                {
                    ServidorErro.Erros.Add(erro);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
        else if (dataCheck2 >= timeoutCheck)
        {
            threadAgent.Interrupt();
            threadsFinalizadas++;
            totalThreadsFinalizadas++;
            servidoresErro.Add(mensagem);
            Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ";" + "Servidor=" + mensagem + ";" + "Processo=FIM;Status=ERROR;Desc=Timeout:" + DateTime.Now.Subtract(dataCheck).ToString());
        }
        else
        {

            threadsFinalizadas++;
            totalThreadsFinalizadas++;
            servidoresErro.Add(mensagem);
            Log(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ";" + "Servidor=" + mensagem + ";" + "Processo=FIM;Status=ERROR;Desc=Unknown");
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }

    Log2(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + ";" + "Termino " + mensagem + " " + dataCheck2.ToString());
```

});

[image: Erro]

Não entendo o que preciso fazer para não ocorrer já que as variáveis não estão nulas.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: O código postado não corresponde ao da imagem, então fica mais complicado ajudar, ficamos tendo que atirar em um alvo móvel. Espero que esse `catch` tenha sido colocado no desespero, ele só está atrapalhando. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: Na verdade é uma parte do código, e o erro acontece exatamente no bloco que coloquei.

Comment: E sim, foi no desespero esse catch rs, nao entendi o erro se estou declarando as variaveis dentro do mesmo bloco e a elas não são nulas

Answer (score -1):

Ao colocar o Thread.Sleep(100);

Dentro do laço While o problema foi resolvido, por algum motivo ele estava gerando timeout na função.

```
while (threadAgent.ThreadState.ToString() != "Stopped" && DateTime.Now.Subtract(dataCheck) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente estamos falando de um erro de cross threading então. As variáveis dentro do método estão declaradas fora da instância das novas threads? Se for isso, colocar o sleep só vai mascarar o problema